# kodi (OpenELEC) is not showing the mouse pointer

Tags: kodi, openelec, mouse

I have installed last OpenELEC version on by Raspberry+ using BerryBoot.
All is working fine, except the mouse pointer is not shown.
The functionality exists, I mean, when I move the mouse the screen reacts giving focus to the componen that, I suppose, I'm pointing. But the issue is that there is no mouse pointer.

Do you know if there is any setting which allows hide/unhide the mouse pointer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use keyboard or remote, it is better(sort of). But, no, as far as my knowledge goes, there is no setting to hide/un hide the cursor.

Comment: I have installed kodi via retropie (guess that's from the repo) but when I boot up kodi, I do see a mouse pointer. Maybe it's openELEC that doesn't have a pointer? Maybe OSMC has it? I don't use a mouse, just my TV remote over CEC, but could test it out when I get home.